# Office 365: Get Subscription License Count

Tags: office365, office365api

I am attempting to get the number of licenses that I have on my Office 365 account.

When I log in to the Office 365 portal and view Billing > Licenses, I'm given a table with the name of the subscription and the number of valid, expired, and assigned licenses for that subscription.

For example, [image]

Is there a way to pull this same information from any of the Office 365 APIs or reporting services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Up Till now there has been no API or reporting service for getting subscription license count.

I have added an image from API catalog of Office 365 and as per the discussion with internal O365 team from Microsoft - There will be a lot more APIs coming in future to giving more control to developers of O365 platform.

[image]